# proving identity for statistical distance

Tags: discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

How do I show the following identity?

Let $\vec{\rho}_X$,$\vec{\rho}_Y$ denote the probability distributions over a finite set $R$ respectively.

Prove that 
$\Delta(\vec{\rho}_X,\vec{\rho}_Y)=\max_{S\subseteq R}P_X(S)-P_Y(S)$ where the maximization is taken over all subsets $S\subseteq R$.

Comment: Can you show us the definition of $\Delta(\vec{\rho}_X,\vec{\rho}_Y)$?

Comment: @freak_warrior: $\Delta(\vec{\rho}_X,\vec{\rho}_Y)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{r\in R}{\left|P_X(r)-P_Y(r)\right|}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$a=\sum_{\substack{r\in R\\ P_X(r) \ge P_Y(r)}} P_X(r) - P_Y(r) $$
$$b=\sum_{\substack{r\in R\\ P_X(r) \lt P_Y(r)}} P_X(r) - P_Y(r)$$
Observe that $a+b=0$ and $\sum_{r \in R} |P_X(r)-P_Y(r)| =  a - b$. Hence $\Delta(\vec\rho_X, \vec\rho_Y) = a$
Now again observe that if $A=\{r|r \in R \text{ and }  P_X(r)\ge P_Y(r)\}$,
$$max_{S\subseteq R}\ P_{X}(S)-P_{Y}(S) = P_X(A)-P_Y(A) = a = \Delta(\vec\rho_X, \vec\rho_Y)$$ which was to be shown.

Comment: Thanks, how about this question? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576947/statistical-distance-identity