# statistical distance identity

Tags: discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

How do I show the following?

Let $\vec{\rho}_X$,$\vec{\rho}_Y$ denote the probability distributions over a finite set $R$ respectively, and consider a function $f: R\to[0,1]$.

Prove that 
$\Delta(\vec{\rho}_X,\vec{\rho}_Y)=\max_{f}\left|\mathbb{E}(f(X))-\mathbb{E}(f(Y))\right|$ 
where the maximization is taken over functions $f: R\to[0,1]$, and $\mathbb{E}(f(X))$ denotes the expectation value of $f(X)$.

Comment: It is not hard to find the function which maximizes the Expectation difference. Hint: See my solution to your previous question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/576865/93882)

Comment: Is it some indicator function? @Miheer

Comment: @freak_warrior: Of course ;)

Comment: @Miheer: Can you write the function $f$? I tried to figure it out, but failed terribly. :(

Comment: $f = 1_A$ where $A = \{r : r \in R, P_X(r) \ge P_Y(r)\}$ should work.